# Native .Net installer/bootstraper

Tags: .net, visual-c++, native, bootstrapper

I want a desktop application to provide a smooth user experience through deployment. In case a user purchases an app through the web site, and downloads it, I need it to detect .Net framework, that is installed on a client machine, and if it is not of a required version - download and install the one needed right a way, without asking user to click anything.

For that, my downloaded executable should be a native application. I need it to have a good look, so I am thinking to use QT for GUI of the this bootstraper.

Main question is: will I be able to configure a QT project to compile into a singe executable, without the need carry some qt.dll's around, to support GUI elements? If not, and Qt will require me to carry around a satelite dll's, what is the "visual" way to design an app I need, without the need to resort to using WinAPI? C++ Builder perhaps?

P.S. I can't just use a standard .net setup project / msi installer. Even though it allows to detect and warn about the dependency, an experience of downloading it still requires a lot of user clicking, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about QT, but C++ Builder can definitely do what you want...

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can write the bootstrapper using Visual C++, C++Builder, or Delphi (any IDE that generates native executable).

But installer generators such as Inno Setup/InstallAware can also achieve the same goal, which are much better and flexible than what Microsoft offers.